# How to make jtable transferhandler highlight a row when implementing DnD?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

How to highlight the row under the cursor when dragging and dropping?

I need to identify the row in the jtable I'm dragging onto, not the insert position which the default transfer handler supplies out of the box.

Having identified the row itself, I expect that `importData`(TransferSupport support) can handle the fine details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myTable.setDropMode(DropMode....); is what I was after.

Options are:

```
 DropMode.USE_SELECTION
    DropMode.ON
    DropMode.INSERT
    DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT
```

The final one ( DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT) provided me with more than what I needed, (which is good) - the ability to distinguish between inserting a row between other rows, AND an indication of dropping data ONTO a row.
I should have done more research initially before posing the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the themes for RadGridView. Currently, the ControlTemplate for GridViewRow did not have Template bindings for BorderBrush and BorderThickness. This means that the change you are making did not get propagated to the Border element that is in the GridViewRow's template. We will fix this for our official release.

However, there is a way you can do this in the current situation. You should just find the border in the template. Here is an example of how to achieve this:

```
var border = rowItem.ChildrenOfType<Border>().FirstOrDefault();

if(border != null) {

    border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);

}
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm explaining myself well. When I drag onto my jtable, a line shows up showing me where the drop will be inserted into the table. I don't want to see this line, I want java to highlight the Row the cursor is hovering over, and pass the index of that row back to me.